# I am unable to connect my Samsung GT-S7562 with data cable

Tags: drivers

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 and Samsung Galaxy S Duos. I am unable to connect it with my system via Data cable. Please tell me steps so that I can transfer my files to my system.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the USB debugging mode under Developer options is unchecked. Now, it is time to open the terminal (CTRL +ALT+T) and install MTP tools

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

When the installation is finished, connect your Android device to your Ubuntu box and Ubuntu Linux will recognize the device.
[image]

See more [here](http://www.unixmen.com/connect-your-android-galaxy-tablet-to-ubuntu-via-usb/#sthash.0869XnFP.dpuf)